# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contains') JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, dom

The following code is producing an error for me

```js
tab.addEventListener("click", (e) => { 
  e.preventDefault();
  if (document.getElementsByTagName("a").classList.contains("active")) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("a").classList.remove("active"); 
  } else {
    console.log("nothing")
  }
})
```

It is producing this error in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contains')
```

I am confused, because I am not sure why this error is happening. Even stranger, when the `classList.remove("active")` is outside of the conditional, the same error occurs, with `contains` replaced with `add`. Can someone explain to me why this error is happening?

Thank you

Comment: [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a live HTML collection of elements. You can't use `classList` on it. If you're picking up all the anchors you'll need [to iterate over the collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), and check and set the classList of each element separately.

Answer (score -2):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

returns an array

`.classList` will be undefined on an array

So when you try to access the `contains()` method you get the error that you are seeing.

A solution would be to use a filter and for each on the array.